# How to do Navigator.popUntil properly when using different animations for each push

Tags: flutter

I am trying to rebuild iOS app in Flutter, but facing a problem with navigation.

Here what I am trying to do:

1. List of Added Exchange Pairs with Add button (A screen)
2. Add button opens Picker with Exchanges (B screen) with transition from bottom to top.
3. By tapping on exchange it pushes new Picker with Pairs (C
   screen) with transition from right to left.
4. when user taps on pair it closes all pickers at once and deliver result of picking to A screen.

I have tried double pop and popUntil but result always same, I see 2 back transitions (left to right and top to bottom) at same time.

### How it looks in iOS native app:

[image: How it looks in iOS native app]

### How it looks in Flutter app:

[image: How it looks in Flutter app]

### Solved with nested Navigator

Wrapped Screen B with Navigator and used this navigator to push screen C, on screen C used root navigator to pop. Result is below:
[image: Final result]

Comment: You can use pushReplacement if you don't want to see 2 back transitions.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but `pushReplacement()` only replaces top route. In additional I don't wanna recreate Screen A, and I want to deliver result of picking to Screen A.

Comment: Try 'pushAndRemoveUntil'
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html

Comment: hi try this `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> r) => false);` and see if this works, where `/` is your main route which can be replaced with the route you wanted to navigate to .

Comment: @Mahi, I have tried, it even looks more worse =), Main screen A show at the end from bottom to top, when expected is picker going from top to bottom and main screen A stays without animation.

Comment: Updated title to better reflect the problem

Comment: @nonameden Do you mind sharing a code example for your solution above? It's easier to visualize that way. Thanks.

Comment: @westoque Added answer, let me know if it is unclear.

Comment: @nonameden Thanks! I had a similar solution but continuously pushed to the new `Navigator` instead of using named routes.

Comment: I had a similar issue and using a nested `Navigator`, then calling pop on that `Navigator` is a great idea. Thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: Don't do Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> r => false)); If you have a global scaffold key on your home page, that will result in the "Duplicated GlobalKey detected in Widget Tree" error. Prefer Navigator.popUntil( context,ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName),);

Answer (score 6):

Here the example of how I solved it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  MaterialPageRoute.debugEnableFadingRoutes = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _result = "--";

  void _openSubscreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).push<String>(
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: RouteSettings(name: '/subscreen'),
        builder: (context) => SubScreen(),
      ),
    ).then((result) => setState((){
      _result = result;
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'Result from navigator:',
            ),
            new Text(
              _result,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 32.0,),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: _openSubscreen,
              child: Text('Start flow'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          final path = routeSettings.name;
          if (path == '/') {
            return new MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: routeSettings.copyWith(isInitialRoute: true),
              builder: (_) => SubScreenPage1(),
            );
          } else if (path == '/nexpage') {
            return new MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: routeSettings,
              builder: (_) => SubScreenPage2(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubScreenPage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: OutlineButton(
        child: Text('Next sub page!'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/nexpage');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubScreenPage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: OutlineButton(
        child: Text('Deliver result!'),
        onPressed: () {
          final date = DateTime.now().toString();
          Navigator
              .of(context, rootNavigator: true)
              .pop('Delivered at $date');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. What you're essentially doing is creating a new navigation stack to handle a "modal workflow" that will use matching animations to start and finish the workflow, no matter how many pages are in between. Thank-you!

Comment: I've tried this myself, but I'm stumbling accross a problem when I `pop` the navigation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/64755190/3147305

Comment: `routeSettings.copyWith(isInitialRoute: true),` Hey @nonameden this code error, because property `isInitialRoute` not found in method `copyWith`

Answer (score 6):

When you build your `MaterialApp` by setting `home:` and `routes:` you can achieve "pop to root" without hardcoding what route to pop until by;

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(
  context,
  ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName),
);
```

Because `Navigator.defaultRouteName` will be set to whatever you set `home:` to.

Going a bit off-topic but, this is especially nice if you have "variable" home screen, as in using a `FutureBuilder` to decide what will be the home screen. For example, if you are showing a splash screen until you are loading the initial state from disk.

```dart
home: isUserLoggedIn
    ? HomePage()
    : FutureBuilder(
        future: () async {
          print('Initializing');
          print('Waiting For NoReason');
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          print('Initialization Complete');
        }(),
        builder: (_, snap) {
          if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return SplashPage();
          } else {
            return LogInPage();
          }
        },
      ),
```